# Unable to add data to new column after rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and trying to add a column to my existing model.  I run a rails migration command in my terminal to generate the following migration code

```
class AddPlatformToApps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :apps, :platform, :string
  end
end
```

I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

and the field is added to my database.

I updated each of the views that will utilize the new field.  If I add a value into the database manually, I can see the data app.  However, if I try to add or edit existing form data through the app the new column data is not saved.

**Before Save**

[image]

**After Save**

[image]

**App Params (updated)**

```
def app_params
    params.require(:app).permit(:name, :desc, :in_house)
end
```

Comment: There are many reasons that this could be misbehaving.  I suspect it may have something to do with your strong params.  Could you show us your strong params method in app controller?

Comment: Please answer this question with your comment so I can accept it.  I updated the params to use the new field and it works, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are being filtered by strong params.  So change...

```
def app_params
    params.require(:app).permit(:name, :desc, :in_house)
end
```

to...

```
def app_params
    params.require(:app).permit(:name, :desc, :in_house, :platform)
end
```

And then your params will allow you to pass the attribute `platform` for mass assignment.