# How do I add a string to an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a model called House and added several strings to that model. Now I need to add a couple of new strings to that model.

I typed the following into the command line..

```
rails generate model House location:string House property:string
```

and so on but that returned the following:

```
invoke  active_record
conflict    db/migrate/20150206100119_create_houses.rb
Another migration is already named create_houses: /Users/davidspringate/Sites/houseboard/db/migrate/20150203145217_create_houses.rb. Use --force to replace this migration or --skip to ignore conflicted file.
```

How do I add those strings to the model? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: duplicate with many other questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331623/unable-to-add-data-to-new-column-after-rails-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails g migration AddColumnsToHouse column_name1:type column_name2:type
```

then run `rake db:migrate`

here, `column_name1/column_name2` is the desired column name and `type` is string, float etc.

Please see: [Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: So I've added two new strings how you suggested but just realised I needed to add a couple more strings but now if I try to do the same thing it  returns a conflict saying 'another migration is already add_columns_to_house.rb'. How do I add those new strings?

Comment: `rails g migration AddOtherColumnsToHouse column_name1:type column_name2:type`  
Please see the link for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a migration to intereact with the current tables

```
change_table :products do |t|
  t.remove :description, :name
  t.string :part_number
  t.index :part_number
  t.rename :upccode, :upc_code
end
```

The first will remove a column, the second and third add a column and the fourth rename.

You can see more about migration [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g migration add_columns_to_house property:string
```

then do

```
rake db:migrate
```

or `rails g migration add_columns_to_house`

& then on migration file

```
def change
  add_column :house, :property, :string
end
```

then do

```
rake db:migrate
```